# vgrename on root VG - grub2 issues

Tags: centos7, lvm, grub2

I'm struggling to update grub2 after using 'vgrename' on my root VG in Centos 7.
I ran 'vgrename' successfully, then edited /etc/fstab with the VG name, then edited 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=' in /etc/default/grub with the new VG name, then attempted to run grub2-mkconfig. It's at this point I get the error:

```
# grub2-mkconfig
/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of ‘/dev/mapper/centos_prod--stor01-root’.
```

This canonical path it's pointing to is the old VG name. I don't understand this as I assumed that updating the VG name in /etc/default/grub would have resolved that?
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Running into this exact same issue in CentOS 7 right now :/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if all the steps are necessary for centos, or if more are required, but I hope the following helps.

For SLES 12 SP1, I had to modify the following files after doing **vgrename** or **lvrename**:

- /etc/default/grub
- /etc/sysconfig/bootloader
- /etc/fstab

---

In /etc/default/grub, I also added the following lines:

- GRUB_DEVICE=/dev/VGname/LVname
- GRUB_DEVICE_UUID=e35b6f76-15b7-44ef-8bea-cd2c1ef8a547

---

After that, you must remake the grub config using grub2-mkconfig; however, there seems to be an issue with this script if you are modifying the device path. I had to modify a line (159 for me, should be close) in it to say:

- GRUB_DEVICE="`${grub_probe} --target=device /`" **|| true**

The key difference is the **true** part. Otherwise, grub2-probe will throw an error, propagating up to grub2-mkconfig, because it finds the current device instead of where the new device will be.

Instead of just running grub2-mkconfig, I ran mkinitrd, which runs through that and dracut, which allows the kernel to load the proper filesystems to boot up.

Comment: Thanks, in Debian stretch the same line is in /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig and there was a second very similar line for /boot that needed the same change.

I opted to replace it with `GRUB_DEVICE=/dev/VGname/LVname` there instead of adding the `|| true`

Answer (score 3):

This annoyance is due to a bad assumption by grub.

If I ran `vgrename centos7 vg_centos7` to change the name of the volume group, then:

```
# df -h /
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos7-root  6.5G  1.3G  5.3G  20% /

# ls /dev/mapper
control  vg_centos7-root  vg_centos7-swap
```

The name of the mounted volume and the `/dev/mapper` symlink no longer match. In this scenario, grub2 uses the name of the currently mounted volume (centos7-root) and fails when it can't find it in `/dev/mapper/` (as it was just renamed to vg_centos-root).

You can remount and chroot to work around this, as follows:

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg_centos-root /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys/ /mnt/sys
mount --bind /run/ /mnt/run
mount --bind /boot/ /mnt/boot

cat << EOF | chroot /mnt
grub-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub/grub.cfg
exit
EOF

umount /mnt/boot
umount /mnt/run
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt
```

Comment: I still get error `cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device /dev/mapper/centos7-root` on `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`. Any idea why ?

Answer (score -1):

My way works well in CentOS 7 and 8.

Current vg and lvs

```
# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  cl   1   4   0 wz--n- <325.97g 4.00m
# lvs
  LV      VG Attr       LSize    Pool
  root    cl -wi-ao----  <46.57g
```

Plan to
change vg name from *cl* to *vg_sys*
and
change lv name form *root* to *lv_root*

rename vg and lv name

```
vgrename -v cl vg_sys
lvrename /dev/cl/root /dev/vg_sys/lv_root
```

Then modify */etc/fstab*, */boot/grub2/grub.cfg*, */etc/default/grub*, */boot/grub2/grubenv*

```
sed -i 's/cl-root/vg_sys-lv_root/g' /etc/fstab
sed -i 's/cl-root/vg_sys-lv_root/g' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sed -i 's/cl\/root/vg_sys\/lv_root/g' /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sed -i 's/cl-root/vg_sys-lv_root/g' /etc/default/grub
sed -i 's/cl\/root/vg_sys\/lv_root/g' /etc/default/grub
sed -i 's/cl-root/vg_sys-lv_root/g' /boot/grub2/grubenv
sed -i 's/cl\/root/vg_sys\/lv_root/g' /boot/grub2/grubenv
```

Make sure all four files are modified correctly.
After OS rebooted, it works as well as what you planed.